# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected x fields in line y, saw z

Tags: pandas, parsing, encoding

I am new to python. Ran across below error when trying to read in dozens of zip files into a signle df. Each zip file contains a csv file. I searched extensively on stack overflow and haven't find a solution yet. my suspicion is that this csv contains Chinese characters as well as urls.
my code:

```
import os
import zipfile
import pandas as pd
import glob
file_path = os.getcwd() #obtain file path
allFiles = glob.glob(file_path + "/*.zip") #return list of all file names
list_ = []
for file in allFiles:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file) as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f.open(f.namelist()[0]),encoding='latin-1',header=None)
        list_.append(df)
        df = pd.concat(list_)
df
```

and here is the error message:

---

```
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-471e9d0ab709> in <module>()
      6 for file in allFiles:
      7     with zipfile.ZipFile(file) as f:
----> 8         df = pd.read_csv(f.open(f.namelist()[0]),encoding='latin-1',skiprows=[0, 1],header=None)
      9         list_.append(df)
     10         df = pd.concat(list_)

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    653                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    654 
--> 655         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    656 
    657     parser_f.__name__ = name

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    409 
    410     try:
--> 411         data = parser.read(nrows)
    412     finally:
    413         parser.close()

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1003                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
   1004 
-> 1005         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1006 
   1007         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1746     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1747         try:
-> 1748             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1749         except StopIteration:
   1750             if self._first_chunk:

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:10862)()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:11138)()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:11884)()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:11755)()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:28765)()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 9, saw 2
```

Comment: Do you have a couple of samples of that is in the zip files?

Comment: try using "error_bad_lines=False" in the read_csv

Answer (score 0):

I tried using "error_bad_line=False", yet it returns another error.

Eventually, I managed to by pass this problem by renaming both the zip file titles and the CSV file titles, keeping only numbers for my own reference. And changed the read_csv encoding to "latin-1".